# Google Apps Directory Sync issue in Windows 2008 R2 Data-centre

Tags: g-suite

I am using the Windows server 2008 R2 Data-centre 64 bit version.

I have installed the Active Directory and Google Apps Directory Sync 64 bit version

All the connections to the LDAP server and Google Apps server are successful. Now When I enter the search rule i.e LDAP user sync rule in User Accounts of GADS. I received the "Received 0 Results"

Rule applied:

Scope = Sub-tree
Rule = objectClass=person for Active Directory
Base DN = cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com

Scope = Sub-level
Rule = objectClass=person for Active Directory
Base DN = cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com

Scope = Object
Rule = objectClass=person for Active Directory
Base DN = cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com

Still receiving the same error when searched in the LDAP browser with the Base DN and rule the LDAP browser extract all the users in the Base DN with the search rule.

Can someone please let me know where i went wrong or what can i do further to resolve this issue really need it badly.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could use some more detail; maybe some screenshots of your configuration? I'm not sure why you have three rules or where exactly you're putting them. Try running your exact LDAP query in AD UC and see what it returns.

Comment: Hey Thanks r.tanner.f for response. The issue is resolved I put the correct search rule and Base DN was incorrect so I changed it and it work...